# Adding wireguard-go into Go app for Mac and Windows

Tags: go, wireguard

Writing an application in Go that will create and delete WireGuard tunnels. Need to add wireguard-go within the application rather than installing as a separate WireGuard program.
For linux it is easy, I did it.
For Windows and Mac I'm not finding right help.
I have wireguard-go compiled for Mac and windows along with wg, wg-quick.